# restricting edit route -- unless condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm making a video-game review website for practice -- and the idea that I'm trying to accomplish is:

You can only review a videogame once

BUT

When a new news article about the game is published, you can edit and change your review, until another article is published again.

Currently, I have this logic that hides and shows the Edit link -- but ofcourse, the route is still active.

How do I restrict the edit route when no new article is added?

Below is the logic, followed by the routes. If you need other files, please do let me know. Thanks in advance

The way this works is - if the last news object was created AFTER your review was last updated -- then you can see the link to edit your review.

```
<% if @news.last.created_at > preview.updated_at && preview.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <p><%= link_to "edit", edit_game_preview_path(@game.id, preview.id) %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root "games#index"

  resources :games do
    resources :news
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
    resources :previews, except: [:show, :index]
  end

  resources :platforms
  resources :genres

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to have users "only review a videogame once", I'd recommend the following model validation in app/models/review.rb ([here's more info on validates_uniqueness_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)) in addition to just hiding the "edit" link.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :game_id.
```

You'll need to restrict both the "edit" page and the "update" action to meet your needs, but I don't understand where "previews" come in.

I can edit my answer if you can explain the "previews", but here's the code to allow users to "edit and change their review, until another article is published".

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :restrict_access_modify, :only => [:edit, :update]

  ...

  private

  def restrict_access_modify
    # Make sure that Reviews.find(params[:id]) isn't repeated.
    @review = current_user.reviews.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(:back, notice: "A new article has already need posted") if News.last.id > @review.new_id
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks sooo much. this is perfect and works. previews are just comments you can make before a game is published. once it's published, you can leave reviews :) so basically i created 2 phases -- a preview phase, and review phase. the phases are determined if `Time.now < release_date`

Comment: Any opinions on using a state machine? You could use it to control what actions users are taking and automatically trigger actions to be taken (ex: Tweet or email).

Answer (score 0):

I to hide to the link when no news is there you can use the code below. Also there is no need to call the id of the user and compare, you can do a direct == as below.

```
<% if !@news.empty? and @news.last.created_at > preview.updated_at && preview.user == current_user %>
    <p><%= link_to "edit", edit_game_preview_path(@game.id, preview.id) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks so much. it's much cleaner without the id. and didn't know about the .empty? method. instead, i used `@news.count == 0`, which works too, but not clean.

Comment: You don't restrict the route, you restrict the controller action.

Comment: thanks so much guys. i restricted the action. perfect.